# Why does my app crash?

Tags: android, text, textview, android-edittext, edit

I am trying to edit the TextView on clicking a button...
This is the xml part of code

```
TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:editable="true">
/TextView>
Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="write" />
```

On clicking the button write function has been called...
My app crashes as soon as this write function is called...

```
public void write(){
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text.setText(Integer.toString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
public void write(View view){ 
TextView text=(TextView)view; // can do like this instead of findViewById
text.setText(Integer.toString(1));
}
```

As @Doomsknight commented

Your method `write` requires the View parameter, even if its not used. Else it wont find the method you are trying to call.

Comment: yep. it requires the View parameter, even if its not used. Else it wont find the method you are trying to call. +1